# Google channel api not working in ie7

Tags: google-app-engine

I am facing problem with google javascript channel api in ie7 browser. Its not firing onOpen method. I am loading talkgadget channel.js file in my webpage.

Here is the code:

```
   // Not firing in production 
   onOpened = function(){ } 
   onMessage = function(){ } 
   // Create google channel 
   var cd_google_channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(channelId); 
   Channel_Socket = cd_google_channel.open(); 
   Channel_Socket.onopen = onOpened;
   Channel_Socket.onmessage = onMessage; 
   Channel_Socket.onerror = onError; 
   Channel_Socket.onclose = onClose;
```

Please suggest on this.

Comment: did you read this already? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/K7BwzqTjaNE/iDEikqja2-MJ apparently they say that you should try deploying it because on the dev server it has not a stable behaviour

Comment: Hi Samuele,Thanks for the response. I have tried with dev server and production. It seems different behaviour in both the cases. In development, fires onOpen and didnt fire onMessage. In production non of the messages will fire. This appeares only in ie7. remaning all are working fine.